# Climb down ladder in 2D platformer game

Tags: unity-game-engine

For my game, the player character requires to climb up and down ladders those are placed in the gameplay area.

[image]

At present, I can able to climb up for my player character to climb down at present I don't have anyway. Because platform box collider applied with platform effector, so for the climb up, effector does not create any problem but now after reaching the top, it becomes solid platform so now I can't able to move downside.

For climbing up, I have followed this tutorial: [How To Make 2D Ladders In Unity - Easy Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln7nv-Y2tf4)

I am looking to implement some physics so I can reach downside to the ladder after reaching top.

Comment: Follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBSHz-ee8Sk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have managed to solve this, and the game is published in the stores.
You can check using the below link:
[Humpty Trumpty's Border Wall](https://www.gaminguruz.com/game-humptytrumptyborderwall)

This is my overall physics setup for the stair:
[image]

I have applied a trigger collider to my stair object and disable player gravity scale when the player within the stair.
Then after within the trigger enter and exist, I have done this:

```
Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(m_CapsuleCollider, myStair.platformCollider, false);
```

Disable collision between player and platform colliders when the player is within the stair.
I don't think, Platform Effect 2D becomes useful to me in this process but I didn't remove this to remain in the safer side.

So you have to keep a reference of the platform object which is attached to Stair.
I hope you will get a general idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 boolean variables isClimbingUp and isClimbingDown which depend on pressed key and a second ray, which will check -Vector2.up direction. Then just add one more 'else if' statement for down direction.

Comment: But I don't want to specify any key or button to use a ladder if the ladder is in the player area and player press up button then he should require to start climbing and opposite on press down button then climb down.